Exponentiating a tensor product of operators acting on disjoint qubit registers
Consider a problem of implementing $\operatorname{e}^{i\bigotimes_j O_j}$, where all the $O_j$ terms act on disjoint sets of qubits.
Assume that efficient circuits implementing individual $\operatorname{e}^{i\ O_j}$ are known.
Moreover, if necessary, one can also assume that the corresponding registers are relatively small so that efficient circuits $U_j$ for diagonalizing $O_j$ are known (different definitions of "small" or any other assumptions on $O_j$ are welcome too).
Is there a way to efficiently and exactly implement $\operatorname{e}^{i\bigotimes_j O_j}$?
My question is driven by the desire to generalize a well-known procedure for exponentiating Pauli terms $\operatorname{e}^{iXYZ\ldots}$, which is achieved by first rotating to eigenbases of individual qubits, and then using the cascade of $\text{CNOT}$s as in Fig 4.19 of Nielsen&Chuang.

I think the following would work:

Perform phase estimation individually against each $O_j$, creating phase estimate registers $a_j$.
Compute the superposed product $t = \prod_j a_j$.
Phase by an amount proportional to $t$.
Uncompute $t$.
Uncompute each $a_j$.

For the Pauli operator case it's easy to see why this works. Each operator has an eigenvalue of -1 or +1, and computing the product $t$ accumulates the -1 factors into one spot, so that when you phase by an amount proportional to $t$ you are phasing forward if there's an even number of -1s and backward if there's an odd number.

This looks great, thanks! Will accept upon comprehending.

Hi @CraigGidney! How do we compute 2? What is meant by "phase by the amout"? Also, what are we "phasing"?

@MonteNero See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_phase_estimation_algorithm on how to do phase estimation. "Phasing" means to rotate amplitudes. For example, phasing a state by 45 degrees means to multiply its amplitude by (1+i)/sqrt(2). See https://algassert.com/post/1719

@CraigGidney, thanks for the links and explaining the meaning of phasing. My question wasn't about QPE part, but about computing the product $t$ of phases. Are we talking about some arithmetic multiplier here?

@MonteNero Yes, you use an integer multiplier circuit.

Do you think utilizing $U_j$ could simplify the construction?

@mavzolej You may be able to replace the phase estimation with usage of $U_j$. But it's not enough to just diagonalize, you'd also need to lookup the eigenvalues based on the address in the diagonalized register.
